# Flow long text area input fields never seen as blank

Tags: flow, isblank

I've got a flow screen with a long text area input field. No default value. Then I have a formula `ISBLANK({!Field})` that always returns false. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found the Idea posted related to this issue. Please review them and let me know if it helps ::

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhEAAS

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br4g

Cheers
Tushar Uniyal

Answer (score 1):

Referencing long text areas from formula fields is not possible. 
Reference document thanks to Sumuga: [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_field_limits.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: If you have a reference to back up your claim, please link to it and cite it here. Unsourced claims are not very reliable and may be deleted.

Comment: Reference document : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_field_limits.htm&language=en_US&type=0 .. You can’t use long text area, encrypted, or Description fields in formulas.